# Actualizing something in accordance with something

Tags: prepositions, gerunds

If a trading company sets prices which are much higher than the prices put by the rivals. Then this company carries out marketing research and realizes that its prices on goods do not meet actual market requirements.

Can you say that the company should actualize its prices in accordance with the market ones?

I need the noun instead of the verb.

> Actualizing prices in accordance with the market ones
>
> Adapting prices to the market ones
>
> Making prices more relevant to the market ones

Which of the listed phrases sounds more natural to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the conventional word here is "set": you "set prices in accordance with market conditions" or "set prices to market values".

Comment: So, you suggest the word "set". Okay. What do you think of the other examples?  Are they not good enough? What about 'adapting'?

Comment: "Adapting prices" could work in context. It's an unusual word to use in reference to prices, but possible here. "Actualizing" doesn't really work. That means to take something that doesn't exist and make it exist. But the price already existed, it just wasn't a realistic number. "Making prices more relevant" is possible. It sounds a little awkward to me, but it's not grammatically or logically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to mind.

Actualize is not commonly used and its usage would be 'to make reality.'

1) You can not 'actualize' it when prices being 'actualized' already exists. 
2)It does not specifically convey the meaning of a price change.

In this instance of given choices I would use adapting.

"...adapting prices to the market ones."

It is easier to understand and to the point.

"Making prices..." this works fine but the word 'making' considering the subject matter and educational level to converse on this subject matter seems to tarnish this sentence.

You could do a combo:

"(some entity is) adapting prices in accordance to the more relevant market ones."